# How do i make a WP_Query to get product variations with specific attribute key and attribute value?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How do i make a WP_Query to get WC_Product_Variation with specific attribute key and attribute value?

All i know is how to get WC_Product

```
$all_products_query = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type'         => 'product',
'post_status'       => 'publish',
'posts_per_page'    => '-1',
) );
```

Comment: you want specific meta key and specific meta value?

Comment: i meant product_variations instead of product. And only product_variations with specific key-value. Let's say key: Color, value: red.. So "only get product_variations with color of red"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `meta_query` --refer https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

```
     $args = array(
         'post_type' => 'product',
         'meta_key' => 'key',
         'meta_value' => 'value'
      );
     $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: no, i meant product_variations instead of product. And only product_variations with specific key-value. Let's say key: Color, value: red.. So "only get product_variations with color of red"

Comment: that query is to get WC_Product instead of WC_Product_Variation.

Comment: Make a custom functionality loop all product and check for each of produscts for variation and get them with `$available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();` filtring `$available_variations` with your key and value.

Comment: yes, but that would mean i need to get all WC_Product and query it, which means i cannot paginate it, and it will be slow if i have lots of WC_Product